# Execution failed for task ':app:minifyIsByPassDebugWithR8

Tags: android, obfuscation

I'am using `minifyenable = true` but error in `aapt_rules.txt`

my `build.gradle`

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         
        }
    }
```

error logcat

```
Expected field or method name at /Users/ujangwahyu/REINOVASI/ANDROID/DEV/MS2_Android/app/build/intermediates/aapt_proguard_file/isByPassDebug/aapt_rules.txt:148:33
    -keepclassmembers class * { *** @{(v) -> vm.onClickEnter(v)}(android.view.View); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some days before I also faced the same issue and I fixed it by configuring `gradle.properties` and `build.gradle(project level)`

put below two lines in `gradle.properties`

```
android.enableR8=false
android.enableR8.libraries=false
```

put below lines of code inside `buildscript{}` in `build.gradle(project level)`

```
 configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-base:6.1.0'
        }
    }
```